# cassandra database testing with jmeter

Tags: cassandra, jmeter, performance-testing, cql, cqlsh

I have installed cassandra CQL shell on my local system, I am using jmeter v3.0 for testing the queries per second(QPS) on cassandra CQL shell. I have installed "cassandra support" plugin available in "plugin manager" with jmeter.

I have created keyspace in cassandra(keyspace1), created a table(student) and added some data in CQL shell.

I have added "cassandra properties" from config elements and entered the properties in jmeter.

Here are the properties:

[image: cassandra properties]

I have added "cassandra get" sampler.

added "view results tree" listener.

when I run it I am getting the following error:

> ERROR: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Read a negative frame
>   size (-2080374784)!

[image: view results tree]

I have given the "schema properties" as seen on github.
but no use. I am getting the same error.

Can anyone suggest me how to resolve this error?

> ERROR: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Read a negative frame
>   size (-2080374784)!

I want to use the cassandra samplers for put, get and delete operations on the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the Netflix plugin you are using is somewhat deprecated because it uses the Cassandra thrift API which is deprecated (the plugin did not have a lot of recent commits in github too).

See announcements [here](http://techblog.netflix.com/2016/02/astyanax-retiring-old-friend.html) and [here](http://grokbase.com/t/cassandra/user/161478syw5/announcement-thrift-api-deprecation)

Even if you succeed in your test with this plugin, it would not be very representative of a current client use (hence load).

IMHO you should make your test with  JSR223 groovy scripts (preprocessor and samplers) and use the Datastax standard java driver + CQL in your script. I did it some time ago, it works fine.
(update: documented [here](https://medium.com/@alain.rastoul/jmeter-groovy-testing-cassandra-2269a9df6f0e))

Or may be try [this JMeter plugin](https://github.com/slowenthal/jmeter-cassandra#cassandra-jmeter-plugin-for-cassandra) from a Datastax guy, it seems to use CQL . I didn't tried it, but it looks fine.

HTH,

Alain